# $f_n \rightarrow f$ in measure iff for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N$ s.t. $\mu (\{\mid f_n -f \mid \geq \epsilon \})<\epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

$f_n \rightarrow f$ in measure iff for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N \in \Bbb N $ such that $\mu (\{\mid f_n -f \mid \geq \epsilon \})<\epsilon$ for all $n \geq N$.

For me, it seems direct to prove $f_n$ converges in measure just by definition; however, I'm stuck in the converse direction.

Comment: What's on the right hand side of "iff" is equivalent to the following: for every $\varepsilon>0$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu\{|f_n-f|\geq\varepsilon\}=0$, which is just the definition of convergence in measure. Indeed, not a very exciting exercise.

Comment: @uniquesolution But it is exactly that "iff" which has to be shown. I agree, it is a very easy exercise for someone familiar with the topic. But according to your logic, most math.se questions are "indeed, not very exciting"...

Answer (score 2):

Ok let's attempt the converse direction: Let $\varepsilon > 0$. We want to show that:

$$ \mu (\{\mid f_n -f \mid \geq \varepsilon \}) \to 0 \; n \to \infty $$

But notice that for $\varepsilon > \tilde{\varepsilon}$ it holds that:

$$\{\mid f_n -f \mid \geq \varepsilon \}\subset \{\mid f_n -f \mid \geq \tilde{\varepsilon} \}$$

Therefore it holds that:

$$\mu(\{\mid f_n -f \mid \geq \varepsilon \})\leq \mu(\{\mid f_n -f \mid \geq \tilde{\varepsilon} \})$$

By our assumption, there also exists $N(\tilde{\varepsilon})$ such that:

$$\mu (\{\mid f_n -f \mid \geq \tilde{\varepsilon} \}) \leq \tilde{\varepsilon} \; \forall \; n\geq N(\tilde{\varepsilon})$$

Putting these together: For every $0<\tilde{\varepsilon}<\varepsilon$, there exists $N(\tilde{\varepsilon})$ such that:

$$\mu (\{\mid f_n -f \mid \geq {\varepsilon} \}) \leq \tilde{\varepsilon} \; \forall \; n\geq N(\tilde{\varepsilon})$$

Therefore it follows that $f_n \to f$ in measure.